# What will be the result in indexing the string elements of Ordered Dictionary

Tags: python, optimization, indexing, mixed-integer-programming, ordereddict

```
rescat2idx= [OrderedDict([('EAF', [1]),
          ('AOD', [2]),
          ('LF', [3]),
          ('CC1', [4]),
          ('CC2', [5]),
          ('H_A_S1', range(6, 30)),
          ('H_A_S2', range(30, 54)),
          ('H_B_S2', range(54, 78)),
          ('H_A_S3', range(78, 102)),
          ('H_B_S3', range(102, 126)),
          ('H_A_S4', range(126, 150)),
          ('H_B_S4', range(150, 174)),
          ('EN', [174])]),174]

trans_time = {'TR_S1': 10, 'TR_S2': 4, 'TR_S3': 10}

trans_time_max = {'TR_S1': 240, 'TR_S2': 240, 'TR_S3': 120}

for res_cat, resources in  rescat2idx.items():
        if 'H_B_' not in res_cat:
            continue
        max_wait_time = time_trans_max['TR_S%d' % **(int(res_cat[-1])** - 1)]
```

Note: What will be the output of max_wait_time? Will it work? I am new to python and I found that there is not integer elements in res_cat so how does max_wait_time works?

Comment: what you meant by this `'TR_S%d' % **(int(res_cat[-1])** - 1)` and what you trying to achieve here? What is your expected output with this code snippet ?

Comment: **(int(res_cat[-1])** , Thats what I am trying to figure it out, what shall be the outcome of this line?

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in the code snippet, Which are

1. `rescat2idx` is a list, you need to iterate through `rescat2idx[0]`
2. trans_time dict key change to this `f"TR_S{int(res_cat[-1]) - 1}"`

```
    In [54]: for res_cat, resources in rescat2idx[0].items():
        ...:     if "H_B_" not in res_cat:
        ...:         continue
        ...:     max_wait_time = trans_time_max[f"TR_S{int(res_cat[-1]) - 1}"]
    
    In [55]: max_wait_time
    Out[55]: 120
```

Comment: 1. `rescat2idx` is a Ordered dict as you can see in the first line. so `res_cat` when we will run this for loop `for res_cat, resources in  rescat2idx.items():` , `res_cat` will be the first elements of the dict. `time_trans_max` is `trans_time_max`, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @MargiShah `rescat2idx ` If you check that properly you can see that it's enclosed inside `[ ... ]`. So it's a Ordereddict inside list. Rest is updated and hope you got the answer.

Comment: `for res_cat, resources in res_cat2idx[0].items():
    print(res_cat)` I tried this, `KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for res_cat, resources in res_cat2idx[0].items():
      2     print(res_cat)

KeyError: 0` This is what I am getting

Comment: @MargiShah I wrote as per the sample you shared, If you have any changes from the original sample please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I run the same program. Let me make it simple. I have `rescat2idx= [OrderedDict([('EAF', [1]),
          ('AOD', [2]),
          ('LF', [3]),
          ('CC1', [4]),
          ('CC2', [5]),
          ('H_A_S1', range(6, 30)),
          ('H_A_S2', range(30, 54)),
          ('H_B_S2', range(54, 78)),
          ('H_A_S3', range(78, 102)),
          ('H_B_S3', range(102, 126)),
          ('H_A_S4', range(126, 150)),
          ('H_B_S4', range(150, 174)),
          ('EN', [174])]),174]` When I try to do `res_cat2idx[0].items()` as you did, it is giving me key error 0.

Comment: @MargiShah Check on your comment itself, it's `rescat2idx ` and `res_cat2idx `. Both are different.